# éthos ou ethos?

Tags: diacritiques

Je suis en train de traduire un texte assez difficile du grec en français et je me trouve pas mal de fois coincée dans des héllénismes qui n'ont pas toujours des équivalents en français.

Quand je suis tombée sur ἤθος j'étais sûre que je pouvais utiliser ***éthos*** sans problèmes, mais à mon exaspération j'ai constatè que ce mot [n'existe pas dans tous le dictionnaires](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9thos) (avec ou sans accent).

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ethos/31434) définit ***ethos*** (sans accent) comme:

> Manière d'être sociale d'un individu (vêtement, comportement) envisagée dans sa relation avec la classe sociale de l'individu et considérée comme indice de l'appartenance à cette classe.

Je vais probablement choisir le mot ***esprit*** pour le traduire finalement, mais l'accent d'***ethos/éthos*** m'intrigue. Avec ou sans!?

Comment: *Exaspération* ? Ça semble un peu extrême comme réaction à l'absence d'un mot d'un dictionnaire, non ? J'aurais plutôt dis *surprise, étonnement, contrariété, déception...*

Comment: Oui, je l'ai utilisé comme ironie dirigée vers moi-même :)

Answer (score 1):

Certains acceptent « ethos » comme variante de « éthos ». Voir ces deux entrées au WiKtionnaire : [éthos](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9thos), [ethos](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ethos). On s'aperçoit que le Wiktionnaire comprend une définition supplémenaire dans le domaine de la rhétorique.

Comme dans les deux cas la prononciation du e est « \e\ », il est probablement préférable d'utiliser la forme avec l'accent (ce qui rendra claire au moins la prononciation du e).

Le fait que ce mot n'existe pas dans le TLFi n'est pas une indication de son utilisation dans le français d'aujourdhui. Le TLFi ne comprend que le vocabulaire qui a été enregistré jusqu'à la fin du siècle dernier. Comme le Wiktionnaire a ce mot dans sa liste il s'ensuit que des auteurs l'ont choisi pour leurs écrits ; on le trouve par exemple dans deux dictionnaires dont l'un date de 1839, (rhétorique) ; on le touve dans beaucoup de traductions en ce qui concerne l'autre définition.

[image]

Voici une page d'exemples tirée de Google books qui devrait fournir de nombreux contextes utiles dans le but de savoir si l'utilisation actuelle correspond au terme grec : [exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%C3%A9thos%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr.). C'est un mot qui apparait dans de nombreux ouvrages sérieux et donc il n'y a aucune raison de ne pas l'utiliser.